# Android java.lang.SecurityException occured

Tags: java, android

I am new in Android. And I am Working On Dialer Through Launch Application. And I hide my Application Icon From the Menu. I successfully open the Application from Dialer In jellybean And Kitkat Device but when i open Application in Lollipop and Marshmallow System getting me Exception like,

```
E/GooglePlusContactsSync: Failed to clear out contacts
                                                       java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2 from ProcessRecord{ff7ceee 26321:com.google.android.apps.plus/u0a89} (pid=26321, uid=10089) requires android.permission.READ_CONTACTS or android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS
                                                           at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1620)
                                                           at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1573)
                                                           at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.getContentProvider(ActivityManagerNative.java:3594)
                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.acquireProvider(ActivityThread.java:4799)
                                                           at android.app.ContextImpl$ApplicationContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContextImpl.java:2018)
                                                           at android.content.ContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContentResolver.java:1466)
                                                           at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:475)
                                                           at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:434)
                                                           at dit.a(PG:440)
                                                           at dit.b(PG:1388)
                                                           at diu.run(PG:325)
                                                           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

E/DatabaseUtils: Writing exception to parcel
                                            java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/fs_id from pid=2208, uid=10089 requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()
                                                at android.content.ContentProvider.enforceReadPermissionInner(ContentProvider.java:605)
                                                at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.enforceReadPermission(ContentProvider.java:480)
                                                at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.query(ContentProvider.java:211)
                                                at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:112)
                                                at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:453)
```

And then Application automatic close.

Answer (score 2):

The Android 6.0 (Marshmallow) introduced a new way to deal with permissions on Android. [Read more about it here](http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/index.html)

> Beginning in Android 6.0 (API level 23), users grant permissions to
>   apps while the app is running, not when they install the app. This
>   approach streamlines the app install process, since the user does not
>   need to grant permissions when they install or update the app. It also
>   gives the user more control over the app's functionality; for example,
>   a user could choose to give a camera app access to the camera but not
>   to the device location. The user can revoke the permissions at any
>   time, by going to the app's Settings screen.

You need to declare your permissions at the manifest.
Check for the current state:

```
// Assume thisActivity is the current activity
int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
        Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR);
```

And request them if you need:

```
// Here, thisActivity is the current activity
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
                Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

    // Should we show an explanation?
    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(thisActivity,
            Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)) {

        // Show an expanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
        // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
        // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

    } else {

        // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS},
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);

        // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS is an
        // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
        // result of the request.
    }
}
```

To deal with runtime permission in Android I usually use [this library](https://github.com/Karumi/Dexter). It really helps and reduce the code boilerplate.

Answer (score 0):

From Android 6.0 we need to check if the permission is already granted or not, so in order to read contacts you need to first check if read_contacts permission is already granted or not.

Try :

```
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, 101);
        return;
    } else {
        // permission already granted
    }
```

and Listener after granting the permission

```
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 101:
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // permission granted
            }
            break;
        default:
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
    }
```

Comment: I also Check permission dynamically but it is not Working. I try this Code.